# how can i make Oracle DB query to two table different column subtraction

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE member (
member_no   NUMBER  PRIMARY KEY ,
member_money NUMBER NOT NULL,
);
CREATE TABLE MY_PAY(
pay_no NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
member_no NUMBER,
pay_price number
);
```

I want MEMBER.member_money -(MINUS) MY_PAY.pay_price =??
and ?? insert into MEMBER.member_money

so i make this query

```
UPDATE MEMBER
set MEMBER.member_money = (select sum (MEMBER.member_point) - (MY_PAY.pay_price)
from MY_PAY
where MY_PAY.member_no = MEMBER.member_no
group by MEMBER.member_no)
where MEMBER.member_no =2 ;
```

but it doesn't work.
I'm not English man so i'm not good at English sorry
but i want your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```sql
UPDATE MEMBER m
set member_money = member_money - (select sum(pay_price)
                                   from   MY_PAY p
                                   where  p.member_no = m.member_no)
where  member_no =2 ;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
INSERT INTO member VALUES (2, 2000);

INSERT INTO my_pay
SELECT 1, 2, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 200 FROM DUAL;
```

Then, after the `UPDATE`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM member;
```

Outputs:

> | MEMBER_NO | MEMBER_MONEY |
> | --- | --- |
> | 2 | 1700 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8eb9c9dc2ece4c990b79664ae24b5bd7)*

Comment: Thank you ma bro your my hero!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! god bless you!!! i pray for your happy life thank you!!!!!!!

Comment: Meanwhile, accept/upvote answer you find useful, @송봉재